# why run dockers on AWS

Tags: amazon-ecs

I am familiar with docker containers and understand that they are app containers as alternatives to virtual machines. They are useful because they are more light weight.
I also understand using amazon Ec2 instances allows you have may VMs with separate ip addresses.
My question is why anyone would use amazon ECS (container service)?
I understand that this allows containers share memory but this is not scalable since once you use up all the memory for your EC2 instance that runs the containers, you cannot scale it further.
I already read: [What is the difference between Amazon ECS and Amazon EC2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575584/what-is-the-difference-between-amazon-ecs-and-amazon-ec2)

Amazon ECS sounds like a useless product given that distribution over EC2 instances is more scalable.
What do you guys think?

Comment: Containers offer a wide variety of benefits - process isolation, for example. It can also come in handy if various services have bursty workloads at different times - you can manage maximum capacity across *all* services combined instead of having to handle maximum capacity (and scaling up/down) across each individually. All that said, if you don't like it, don't use it - not everyone has a need for it.

Comment: Just thinking about the effort to manage all VMs and EC2, it's not that easy I can say. Meanwhile, you can move your focus on developing Docker application and let ECS take care of orchestration for you, some of the work is still there with ECS (baced by EC2), but if you are using ECS (backed by fargate), everything is just pure container.